# How to write .htaccess 301 redirect rule for

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect some urls.

I need to direct www.site.com/city-st-key-word-string to www.site.com/city-st/key-word-string.

I have about 500 cities I need to do this for.  Preferably instead of making a redirect rule, I would like to change the keyword string as well.  However, I will end up having 2,500 redirects.

Is it ok to have $2,500 redirects or should I use a redirect rule and if so, what would it be?

Thanks for your help in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would this keyword string be the same for all cities? If yes, then you could create one rule and change the keyword string in the rule (and it would reflect on all redirects).

Individual rewrite rules would look like this -

```
Redirect /city-st-key-word-string http://www.site.com/city-st/key-word-string
```

A single rewrite rule for any city-st would look like this -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)-key-word-string$ $1/$2/key-word-string [R=301,L]
```

A rewrite rule redirecting any /x-x-??? to /x-x/??? (i,e; splitting at the two hyphens) -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)-(.*)$ $1/$2-$3/$4 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!  Yes the keyword string is the same for all cities.

Comment: I ran into an issue with this rule.  Some cities are more than one word. I have:

    www.site.com/austin-tx-key-word-string to www.site.com/austin-tx/key-word-string

and

    www.site.com/round-rock-tx-key-word-string to www.site.com/round-rock-tx/key-word-string.

Any ideas?  Thanks!